What are the common design patterns for updating user data of a desktop/mobile application?
Question:
What are common architecture patterns/strategies of updating user data (think of XML/Json/sqlite/custom binary format) when the format of the data needs to be changed, and when that change would make reading old data (that is already stored on user's machine) invalid?
Are there such patterns and how they are called (so I can research more about them)?
A simple example would be a config stored on the user device as a json
{
    "records: [
        "my_data1",
        "my_data2"
    ]
}

With another version some details for the records need to be added, so the json would look like this
{
    "records: [
        { "tags": ["tag1"], "data": "my_data1" }
        { "tags": [], "data": "my_data2" }
    ]
}

For all the apps I developed I use the same strategy:

store a "version" field that has unique value for each format of the file
for each version have a function that upgrades the format from the previous version to this version. The functions should be self-contained and not call any business logic code, even if it forces to violate DRY. Functions are stored in a list sorted by version (with the version itself)
When loading the file, and before passing it to the rest of the app, the version of the file is searched from the latest to the oldest in the list, and all the functions applied from the next version to the last

This worked well for me so far on sqlite databases, jsons, and custom binary formats. It allowed the rest of the code never have any branching on versions and always assume the code is working with the latest version.
However, this design was made through trials and errors, I can't find any articles of how other people handle user data versioning, not sure even how it's called, and don't know whether there are better ways of doing this and what I may be missing out on.

The keywords are data migration and backward compatibility.

see Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?

For database work is is very common to have upgrade scripts that move from one schema version increment to the next, and a gap of several versions is bridged by applying each incremental upgrade in turn. I don't think this is considered a specific pattern.

What you describe is a fairly standard way of handling backwards compatibility in file/database formats. The process of reading an old file format and then storing the data in the latest format is also called data migration.
Although your method is fairly standard, I am not aware of anyone ever bothering to call it a pattern and give it a name.
Another way of doing data migration is to have a set of upgrade scripts that can read one version and then store the data as the next version. When installing a new version of the main application, the installer would check the old version of the files/database and run the appropriate sequence of upgrade scripts to bring the files/database to the latest version. This is more commonly done with databases that support in-place modification of the schema.
